# Асинхронный lock- это зло или нет?

Tags: c#, .net, асинхронность

Интереса ради, изучал возможность асинхронной блокировки и наткнулся на данный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612602/why-cant-i-use-the-await-operator-within-the-body-of-a-lock-statement), где почти все сказали ТСу, что это зло.

Однако, как объяснить наличие [`SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_SemaphoreSlim_WaitAsync_System_TimeSpan_)?

Comment: стоит обратить внимание что разница между ответами два года, плюс в комментариях есть ссылка на статью [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: с lock вы синхронно блокируете поток, с  SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync асинхронно

Comment: Собственно в вопросе речь шла про `await` внутри `lock`, и как указал @JonSkeet в комментарии - [семафор работает иначе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612602/why-cant-i-use-the-await-operator-within-the-body-of-a-lock-statement/50139704#comment40370203_7612704)

Comment: Локи должны быть максимально простыми и маленькими, и не должны накладываться на this. Если есть необходимость делать лок на асинхронную операцию - ИМХО Вы что-то делаете не так.

Comment: зло натягивать стандартные примитивы на async, а вот async примитивы синхронизации очень полезная штука.

Comment: Асинхронный лок хорош, т.к. не занимает поток. Вопрос в чем?